Material doesn't work correctly after applying scale to the model
I tried to make a glass panel. i created a cube and scaled it, and then created a glass material.

It worked as needed, but then I applied the scale of the cube, and the material stopped working properly.

I tried to unwrap the cube again, but it didn't help. I also created a similar cube, but applied the scale first and then applied the same material, it worked perfectly, so the issue is not in the proportions of the cube, but applying the scale. How can I fix it?

Hello could you please share your file? It could be overlapping faces although I don't know how applying scale could change anything...

First of all, you don't need to unwrap anything - unwrapping is needed to map a texture onto the surface of an object. You are just using plain colors, they don't have mapped to a 2D plane somehow. Before you applied the scale, it was negative on X. So probably you have inverted normals there. Go into Edit Mode, press A to select all, then Shift+N to Recalculate Normals to see if it helps.

Link to my project: https://drive.google.com/file/d/14SkIFDDsQrs79YvTqs6piIi16YWop829/view?usp=sharing

Yes, it was because of the Normals! Thank you,
Gordon Brinkmann.

Please post the solution in the answer section, not in the question. An actual answer is better referenced and can be upvoted and marked as accepted

It was because of the normals. Negative value on X scale axis (-0.018) caused normals to flip when applying the scale, therefore the material worked incorrectly. To solve the problem, I applied the scale, and then recalculated normals by selecting all the faces of the cube in Edit Mode and pressing ⇧ Shift + N. After recalculating the normals the material worked correctly.
